# how to check if the user chose a choice in a spinner

Tags: java, android, spinner

I have a spinner that opens programaticly, and when the user chose an option from the spinner, it closes... is there a way to be notified, or a listener that tells you, when the user chose his choice?
the onItemSelected gets the default item that is chosen automaticly when the spinner is open.

Comment: try this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9699864/select-item-in-spinner-android

Answer (score 1):

set  `setOnItemSelectedListener` to your spinner...

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {

                    Object obj = (Object) parent.getSelectedItem();
            //get clicked position from position    
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {

            //this method is call when nothing choosed by you   

            }
        });
```

Comment: the onItemListener gets the default selected item in the spinner

Comment: first time get default value but when changed,`onItemSelected` is called

Comment: I put a breakpoint inside the onItemSelected and when the listener is opened the debugger stops at that breakpoint, and the value of "position" is 0 (i'm using an array adapter)

Answer (score 0):

Add an `OnItemSelectedListener` to your `Spinner`.

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure if I understand your question correctly but let me try to answer it. The normal and straight forward way would be to add an [OnItemSelectedListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener.html) to the spinner i.e

```
spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener(){
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int pos, long id) {
        // Do whatever you want here    
    }

    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView parent) {
        // Do nothing.
    }
});
```

but this is such a basic thing that I feel like a fool for pointing it out. Anyway [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-spinner.html) is a tutorial on spinner from Android Developer resources. It creates the listener in step 5 and adds it to spinner on step 6.